# How to understand certain steps in the proof of the first fundamental theorem of calculus in Spivak's Calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-explanation

I was going through the proof of the first fundamental theorem of calculus in Spivak's *Calculus* (again!) and there are a few steps that I am just not comfortable with. They don't seem to be adequately explicitly justified.

**Here is the statement of the theorem,** as it appears in Chapter 14 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> Let $f$ be integrable on $[a,b]$, and define $F$ on $[a,b]$ by
>
> $$F(x)=\int\limits_a^x f\tag{1}$$
>
> If $f$ is continuous at $c$ in $[a,b]$, then $F$ is differentiable at
> $c$, and
>
> $F'(c)=f(c)$
>
> (If $c=a$ or $b$, then $F'(c)$ is understood to mean the right- or
> left-hand derivative of $F$)

**Here is the proof,** interspersed with my issues and questions

> We will assume that $c$ is in $(a,b)$; the easy modifications for
> $c=a$ or $b$ may be supplied by the reader. By definition,
>
> $$F'(c)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{F(c+h)-F(c)}{h}$$

The underlying proof technique here seems to be a proof by cases. There are two possible cases, $h>0$ and $h<0$, and in each one we will define numbers $m_h$ and $M_h$ and show that

$$m_h\leq \frac{F(c+h)-F(c)}{h}\leq M_h$$

> Suppose first that $h>0$. Then
>
> $$F(c+h)-F(c)=\int\limits_c^{c+h} f$$
>
> Define $m_h$ and $M_h$ as follows
>
> $$m_h=\inf\{f(x):c\leq x\leq c+h \}$$
>
> $$M_h=\sup\{f(x):c\leq x \leq c+h\}$$
>
> It follows from Theorem 13-7 that
>
> $$m_h\cdot h \leq \int\limits_c^{c+h} f \leq M_h\cdot h$$
>
> Therefore
>
> $$m_h\leq \frac{F(c+h)-F(c)}{h}\leq M_h\tag{1}$$

On to Case 2, $h<0$.

> If $h<0$, only a few details of the argument have to be changed. Let
>
> $$m_h=\inf\{f(x):c+h\leq x\leq c \}$$
>
> $$M_h=\sup\{f(x):c+h\leq x \leq c\}$$

One of the issues that bugs me is that the sets $m_h$ and $M_h$ in case 2 are different from the sets in case 1. In case 1, we are dealing with an interval of points greater than $c$, and in case 2 we are dealing with an interval of points smaller than $c$.

I have no issue with the following derivation, however.

> Then
>
> $$m_h\cdot (-h)\leq \int\limits_{c+h}^c f \leq M_h \cdot (-h)$$
>
> Since
>
> $$F(c+h)-F(c)=\int\limits_c^{c+h} f = -\int\limits_{c+h}^c f$$
>
> this yields
>
> $$m_h\cdot h \geq F(c+h)-F(c)\geq M_h\cdot h$$
>
> Since $h<0$, dividing by $h$ reverses the inequality again, yielding
> the same result as before
>
> $$m_h\leq \frac{F(c+h)-F(c)}{h}\leq M_h\tag{2}$$

So at this point, we've reached the "same" conclusion as in case 1.

**My question is, can we really say that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the same statement?**

> This inequality is true for any integrable function, continuous or
> not. Since $f$ is continuous at $c$, however,
>
> $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} m_h = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} M_h = f(c)\tag{3}$$
>
> and this proves that
>
> $$F'(c)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{F(c+h)-F(c)}{h}=f(c)$$

My second major issue concerns statement $(3)$, and the issue arises from the first issue.

Consider statement $(3)$. Let's try to prove it.

Since $f$ is continuous at $c$ we have

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall h, |h|<\delta \implies |f(c+h)-f(c)|<\epsilon$$

$$\implies f(c)-\epsilon\leq f(c+h)\leq f(c)+\epsilon$$

Therefore, for any $h$ such that $|h|<\delta$ we have that $f(c)-\epsilon$ is a lower bound for the set $A=\{f(x): c-|h|\leq x\leq c+|h|\}$.

Now, the sets

$$B=\{f(x): c\leq x\leq c+h\}, h>0$$

$$C=\{f(x): c+h\leq x \leq c\}, h<0$$

are subsets of $A$, and $B$ and $C$ were the sets used to define $m_h$ and $M_h$ in cases 1 and 2, respectively. Therefore,

$$f(c)-\epsilon \leq m_h \leq f(c+h) \leq M_h \leq f(c)+\epsilon$$

which, if correct, means that

$$|m_h-f(c)|<\epsilon$$

$$|M_h-f(c)|<\epsilon$$

(Though it seems to me we would need four such inequalities, since we actually have two different $m_h$ and two different $M_h$)

Therefore we have shown that

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall h, |h|<\delta \implies \left (|m_h-f(c)|<\epsilon \right ) \land \left ( |M_h-f(c)|<\epsilon \right )$$

ie, $(3)$

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} m_h = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} M_h = f(c)\tag{3}$$

**So my second question is: is this proof of $(3)$ correct?**

I have a feeling it isn't. By the way Spivak breezed over this statement I imagine I am missing something that makes $(3)$ quite obviously true.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same statement, in the sense that for any fixed value of $h$ they define $m_h$ and $M_h$ as the minimum and maximum values of $f$ between $c$ and $c+h$, but acknowledging that when $h > 0$ the $c+h$ point is the right end of that interval, while when $h < 0$ it's on the left (and when $h = 0$ you have $m_h = M_h = f(c)$). So $m_h$ and $M_h$ are really just functions of $h$, and the proof shows that for all reasonable values of $h$ we can state that

$m_h \leq \frac{F(c + h) - F(c)}{h} \leq M_h$

which is actually showing that the function in the middle is bound between the two other functions across all of those values of $h$.

Then, since $m_h$ and $M_h$ are both defined in terms of $f$, we use the continuity of $f$ to show that bounding $h$ winds up bounding the above inequality as well.

Comment: How do we actually show that last result that you mentioned?

Comment: $f$ being continuous means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ you can pick a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ within $\delta$ of $c$ you have $f(x)$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $f(c)$, so $m_h$ and $M_h$ must be in that interval as long as $|h| < \delta$. That leads to the result that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} m_h, M_h = f(c)$ and hence by the squeeze theorem the value between them has the same limit.